# Is there an R function that splits a column into an arbitrary number of multiple field-named columns?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

For example, I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(x=c('a, b, c','b, c', 'd, e'))
```

Ideally I would end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
df.transformed = data.frame(x.a = c(1,0,0),
                            x.b = c(1,1,0),
                            x.c = c(1,1,0),
                            x.d = c(0,0,1),
                            x.e = c(0,0,1))
```

Where each of the possible comma-delimited values within `x` have been separated.

I have coded manual solutions to this problem many times, but this is something I have come across enough times in survey data to make me wonder why this isn't included in a package like `tidyr`, since the `separate` function in that package seems less useful. I would like to be able to do this in one line after loading necessary packages.

Comment: Try `qdapTools::mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$x), ",\\s*"))` or with `tidyverse` `rownames_to_column(df, 'rn') %>% separate_rows(x) %>% mutate(i = 1) %>% spread(x, i, fill = 0)`

Comment: If you need to rename it, chain it with `%>% select(-rn) %>% rename_all(funs(paste0("x", .)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be either done with `qdapTools` where we split the 'x' by `,` followed by zero or more spaces and use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$x), ",\\s*"))
#  a b c d e
#1 1 1 1 0 0
#2 0 1 1 0 0
#3 0 0 0 1 1
```

---

Or we use the `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse) 
rownames_to_column(df, 'rn') %>% #add row names
       separate_rows(x) %>% #split the rows into long format
       mutate(i = 1) %>% #create a column of 1s
       spread(x, i, fill = 0) %>% #spread to wide format
       select(-rn) %>%  #remove unnecessary columns
       rename_all(funs(paste0("x.", .))) #rename if needed
#    x.a x.b x.c x.d x.e
#1   1   1   1   0   0
#2   0   1   1   0   0
#3   0   0   0   1   1
```

NOTE: Just posting my comments as a solution

---

Or another option is from `base R` `table` - No packages used

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$x), ",\\s*"), seq_len(nrow(df))))[2:1])
#       values
#ind a b c d e
# 1 1 1 1 0 0
# 2 0 1 1 0 0
# 3 0 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a row number column, separate `x` into rows and preface each element in `x` with `x.`.  Then run `table` and convert that to a data frame.  If you don't need to preface each name then the line with `paste` can be omitted and if you don't need a data frame (a table is ok) then the last line can be omitted.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
   mutate(row = 1:n()) %>% 
   separate_rows(x) %>% 
   mutate(x = paste("x", x, sep = ".")) %>%
   table %>% 
   as.data.frame.matrix
```

giving:

```
  x.a x.b x.c x.d x.e
1   1   1   1   0   0
2   0   1   1   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   1
```

Note that if we omit the optional lines then we have this:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(row = 1:n()) %>% 
   separate_rows(x) %>% 
   table
```

giving:

```
   x
row a b c d e
  1 1 1 1 0 0
  2 0 1 1 0 0
  3 0 0 0 1 1
```